# Parents of python object

Tags: python, parent-child

I have a bunch of Python objects, all defined independently. They can all be parent/children of one another. This relationship is materialized via the "children" property that each object has. It is a list, potentially empty.

If I want to know the children of an object, i just have to do `MyObject.children`.

**Now I want to retrieve the parent: is there an elegant way of doing that?** The only thing I can think of is to iterate over all my objects and check whether one contains `MyObject` in his children list.

Comment: Do you have multiple parents?

Comment: Probably the best way would be to give `MyObject` a `parent` attribute that you set when the child relationship is set up. It can also be a list if your objects can have more than one parent. If you can't modify `MyObject` you could either keep an independent dictionary, or you can iterate over everything: `next(obj for obj in my_objs if current_obj in obj.children)`.

Comment: When you set `parent` as the parent of `child` or `child` as the child of `parent`, you could do both `child.parent = parent` and `parent.children.append(child)`. This is just and example. You’ll need special handling for changing relationships.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, only one parent per child. It is a tree-like structure